# Oracle's SQL Developer Database Export Results in 2 Digit Years

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle's SQL Developer to export data into CSVs.  I found that Oracle spits out the dates as dd-MMM-yy.  When I bulk insert these files into SQL Server it's interpreting some of the dates incorrectly.  How do I change that?

I'm an Oracle neophyte, so I might be approaching this whole thing incorrectly. I need to transfer a lot of tables/rows from Oracle to SQL Server.  I have a linked server set up in SQL to Oracle, but that takes a really long time to transfer the data.  About 18 hours, and both databases are on the same server, but it gets the dates correct.

I didn't find any good way to accomplish this other than a couple of PL/SQL scripts I couldn't get to work for me.  Is it really that rare that data gets migrated from Oracle to MS-SQL?

Comment: Looks like the Oracle supplied nls_date_format has bee modified from 4 digit year to 2 digit year. :( You can try the following after you connect. "alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy mm dd hh24:mi:ss" or whatever format you require for SQL Server. See [Alter Session](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_2015.htm#SQLRF00901) and [Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)

Answer (score 2):

Well, dates across database vendors are just hell.

The default date format can be set in SQL Developer Preferences > Database > NLS > Date Format. You can also set it in the session as @belayer has commented.

For writing CSV files or for migration projects, I would always try to control the format directly, like

```
SELECT id, TO_CHAR(my_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS my_date, my_column
  FROM my_table;
```

Having said that, there should be a better way to move the data out of Oracle into SQL Server...

Comment: Some hints are at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23782/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-move-data-from-oracle-to-sql-server